# irlba crash with error 'Cholmod error 'invalid xtype' at file:../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 82'

Tags: r, svd

When using the package `irlba` in to run sparse matrix SVD, I have received the following error:

> Error in irlba(X, nu = rank, nv = rank, maxit = 50) :
>         Cholmod error 'invalid xtype' at file:../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 82

Where rank=200 and X is a sparse 34965 x 9109 matrix. I tested for matrix of different size and sparseness, but I always get the same error.

This code runs on EC2 r3.xlarge instances. I am trying to reproduce the problem on my laptop, but did not manage so far.

Any idea?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example (data and code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I reproduce the problem locally by upgrading package irlba 2.0.0 -> 2.1.1. As a conclusion, this problem is a regression issue. I posted an issue on irlba's github page.

I think it is due to the boolean type of the sparse matrix...